# Bold text not aligned with next line

Tags: formatting

"Exercise 1-2", "1-3" and "1-4" are formatted how I like it, but "1-5" is unnaturally shifted to the right as opposed to the rest of my text. What am I missing on the last part?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Create an int variable that contains your age. Name the variable “myAge”.\newline\newline
\textbf{Exercise 1-3}\newline
Suppose you were to create two string variables that are equal to “11.5” and “3.8.” If you were to add them together into a new string variable, what would that equal?\newline\newline
\textbf{Exercise 1-4}\newline
What is the largest number an int can store? Hint: Look on\newline \newline
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types\newline
to answer this. Being able to read programming language documentation is important in the programming field.\newline\newline

\textbf{Exercise 1-5}\newline
Find the bug in this code: \newline
\begin{lstlisting}
/*
Creates integer variables and sets them to different values.

int x = 7;
int y = 3;
int z = 2;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried inserting `\noindent` immediately before `\textbf{Exercise 1-5}`?

Comment: Incidentally, what's with all the `\newline` instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code produces multiple warnings of the form

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--12
```

warning you of the misplaced `\newline`. You should never have these consecutive or at the end of a paragraph. However the single `\newline` after the bold headings while not giving warnings are also wrong as they do not form headings so for example do not prevent a page break immediately after the heading.

The 1.5 example is the only one that starts a paragraph (due to the blank line) so is indented by a paragraph indent.

It would be better to let sections or an Exercise environment declared with `\newtheorem` automatically number the constructs but starting from the posted code a simple global edit to remove the `\newline` and use unnumbered section headings with `\section*` produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xurl}
\begin{document}

Create an int variable that contains your age. Name the variable “myAge”.




\section*{Exercise 1-3}


Suppose you were to create two string variables that are equal to “11.5” and “3.8.” If you were to add them together into a new string variable, what would that equal?




\section*{Exercise 1-4}


What is the largest number an int can store? Hint: Look on
\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types}
to answer this. Being able to read programming language documentation is important in the programming field.





\section*{Exercise 1-5}


Find the bug in this code: 


\begin{lstlisting}
/*
Creates integer variables
and sets them to different values.
*/
int x = 7;
int y = 3;
int z = 2;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed response! I am an absolute beginner to LaTeX (trying to transfer from Word over to it), and your response was very helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderSummers basically in latex if you are numbering something by hand then probably something is wrong, and if you get warnings in the log file, then something is definitely wrong.